# SmartFilterBar Currency with 3 instead of 2 decimals

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, cds

I have the following problem:
[image]

The value of the filter field is converted to a number with 3 decimals. This does not happen with the table values.

The metadata is set to scale=3. I do not know why though, because the ABAP Datafield is set to 2 decimals and the currency is annotated.

Comment: Scale has nothing to do with this. Are you sure the currency is correctly annotated?

Comment: Hi  @BenediktKromer I am pretty sure about the currency annotation since the field in the table is working just fine.

Comment: I just checked the code that is responsible for the creation of the Selection Field. It uses a typed binding that is derived from the metadata which in this case has 3 decimals points because the scale is set to 3.